# How do we decide the sample size we need for ensuring reliability for a test?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, reliability, cronbachs-alpha

There is a test consisting of 6 questions and additional sub-Qs. The test was translated into another language and the questions were adapted, but the reliability of the test was never assessed. The test has an existing rubric and scoring, but only questions 2(a) and 2(c) were self-scored in the rubric as those items were added to the existing test. I have provided details about the scoring and the test questions below.

*MC stands for Multiple-choice
OE stands for Open-ended.*

| Item | Parts | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a (MC) | 2 |
|  | b (OE) | 2 |
|  | c (OE) | 1 |

| Item | Parts | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | a (OE) | 4 |
|  | b (OE) | 1 |
|  | c (MC) | 3 |

| Item | Parts | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | (MQ) | 1 |

| Item | Parts | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | (MQ) | 2 |

| Item | Parts | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | a (OE) | 5 |
|  | b (OE) | 2 |
|  | c (OE) | 2 |
|  | d (OE) | 2 |
|  | e (OE) | 2 |
|  | f (OE) | 2 |

| Item | Parts | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | a (OE) | 2 |
|  | b (OE) | 2 |
|  | c (MC) | 1 |
|  | d (OE) | 4 |
|  | e (OE) | 4 |

I have three questions:

1. How many participants would I need to check the reliability of the test?
2. If this test was applied to a group of 12 participants, how many of them would need to be checked for inter-reliability by another scorer?
3. Since the rubric was self-scored for questions 2(a) and 2(c) as they were adapted/added, how can we ensure reliability?

Comment: Which kind of reliability are you interested in?  (E.g. test-retest? Inter-item?)

Comment: I am interested in internal reliability overall regarding the first Q, the other questions I have are regarding the interrelated reliability.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you say you are interested in internal reliability. Maybe the most common measure of that is Cronbach's alpha, although some people question whether it is the best.

For this (and other measures of reliability) you don't have a hypothesis test and some aspects of power analysis aren't useful. But, as N increases, the accuracy of alpha will increase.

Googling was less productive than I thought it would be, but I did find an [online calculator](https://wnarifin.github.io/ssc/ssalpha.html) for this. (If there is link rot, then this citation may help" APA: Arifin, W. N. (2023). Sample size calculator (web). Retrieved from http://wnarifin.github.io)

That calculator is based on Bonnet (2002). Sample Size Requirements for Testing and Estimating Cronbach's Alpha. J. Educational and Behavioral Statistics. *27(4)* 335-340.

Note that, above I said hypothesis testing wasn't the issue here. It's not that you *can't* do hypothesis testing on alpha, it just doesn't seem apropos here.

Comment: I will be trying the calculator to come up with a needed sample, may I also require your knowledge/expertise on the remaining two questions regarding inter-reliability? (Q2 & Q3)